# Is $L = \{xwyw^r \mid x,w,y \in (a+b)^+ \}$ regular?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

$L = \{ xwyw^r \mid x,w,y \in (a+b)^+ \}$ where $w^r$ is the reverse string of $w$.

If we take $w = {}$minimum string possible ${} = a$ or $b,$ I think it could be regular

Lets say $w=a$, then RE could be $(a+b)^+a(a+b)^+a$

And for $w=b$, then RE could be $(a+b)^+b(a+b)^+b$

 So Overall: $(a+b)^+a(a+b)^+a + (a+b)^+b(a+b)^+b$

Is this enough proof for being regular? While trying to prove non-regularity,
I am not able to prove this language as non-regular.

 *Any thoughts on this? Thank you.*

Comment: Because braces are used for functions in $\rm\LaTeX$, bare braces like you had in your post do not render. In order to render $\{$, you must escape it with a backslash *a la* \{, same for closing braces.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right. But you'll probably have to provide a proof.

A frequent proof technique to show that $L=L'$ is to prove that both $L\subset L'$ and $L'\subset L$. In other words,$\forall \omega.\omega \in L\implies\omega\in L' \land \omega\in L'\implies\omega\in L$.

It's evident that every string in your language is in $L$. That leaves you to prove that every string in $L$ is in your language. You can most easily do this by rewriting $w$ as $w_1w'$ where $w'\in \{a,b\}^*$ and $w_1$ is the first symbol in $w$. Then $$xwyw^R = xw_1w'yw'^Rw_1$$ which is in your language because $w'yw'^R \in \{a, b\}^+$.

Comment: What a great proof ! So, it is regular and my given Regular Expression is correct, right ?

Comment: @SpawN: I believe so. Let me know what your prof says.

Comment: How can we prove that the RE obtained and the Set is equal  ? They say its non regular, but at the same time they're not able to provide any counter. If only I could prove my RE to be same as the set, I can prove them that no such counter will be available.

Comment: @SpawnN: As I said, you prove (1) that every sentence in the set is in your language and (2) that every sentence in your language is in the . The combination of those two proofs shows that the two sets are the same (since a language is just a set of sentences). What problem did you have constructing that proof?

Comment: Your proof is enough, but the professor escaped the problem. Now I asked others, and some of them posted on reddit and had some discussions, they keep saying things like how can you prove RE is equal to Set ? Whatever we derived was From set to RE, they think RE is the superset. Now they asking to prove RE =Set. For now, everyone is saying that it is non-regular with great confidence but they are unable to give any proofs. I have asked knowledgeable people including top rankers, So without a proof, they would keep saying non-regular. I don't know how to prove RE = Set and RE is not superset.

Comment: @SpawN: you need two independent proofs, as I said in the answer and repeated in my comment above. My answer sketches one of the two. I didn't do the other one because it's basically in your question. All that is left is to write it all out formally in one piece, which I think is a good exercise in mathematical rigor. Good luck.

Comment: You mean to say I should just write (a+b)^+ as w ? Like reverse of the proof you wrote ? I did elaborate your proof and converted set to RE denoting RE can accept all the strings of set. Now to prove opposite, are you suggesting that I should write the same steps in opposite manner ? I am sorry, I am new to this subject, thats why I am saying from last 2 replies that I dont know how to prove RE equivalence with set. If possible, please help me with this other proof you're talking about.

Comment: @spawn: you already have the proof in the second paragraph of your question. You want to prove that every sentence matched by the RE is in the set. There are two cases, as you point out: one where the sentence ends with an $a$ and the other where it ends with a $b$. In both cases you take $w$ to be that character so it's clear that the sentence is in the set.